# Consider adding a `<query>` declaration to your manifest when calling this \method;

Tags: java, android, runtime-error, android-implicit-intent

I am getting this **warning on resolveActivity** line while using implicit intents and I am unable to open any website because of that.

```
btnWeb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String v = et.getText().toString();
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(v);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null){
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of `resolveActivity()`. Just call `startActivity()`, but do so in a `try`/`catch`, so you can catch the `ActivityNotFoundException` if there is no Web browser available.